# Do I have multiple python on my computer? and how to uninstall one of them?

Tags: fedora, python

I encountered the problem that `pip install - U numpy` did not update the numpy version in python, which is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390895/why-isnt-pip-updating-my-numpy-and-scipy

Therefore, I doubt whether I have multiple pythons on my computer.

When I ran `which -a python`, it returns the following:

```
/usr/bin/python
/bin/python
```

Does this mean that I have two python on my computer? 
If this is true, I want to uninstall one of them.
I tried `yum remove python`. But I could still see these two pythons, when I ran `which -a python`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which python` only tells you the executable that would be *run* with the command `python`, i.e. it typically returns exactly one result per argument, unless you specify `-a`, in which case it searches all the directories in the `$PATH` environment variable. But in all cases it is the same `python` command.

If you want to know how many versions of python are *installed* on your system, you're better off with `locate /python | grep /bin` or `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` or `yum --showduplicates list python`.

As for your two `python` instances, <strike>chances are one of them is a [symbolic] link</strike>: check with `which -a python | xargs ls -li`. If you want to remove a specific version of python then you'll have to specify that version number on the `yum` command line, e.g. : `yum remove python-2.7.2.el5s2`.

**EDIT**: As [mattdm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2511/mattdm) reports, `/bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin` on Fedora. Consequently you cannot delete python from either of these locations with `rm` otherwise you'd end up deleting python at all. The `-i` argument to `ls` in `which -a python | xargs ls -li` will in this case show that both python instances have the same inode.

Just note that you are not *required* to manually remove version-specific packages since the package manager's purpose is precisely to pull versions adequately, as per dependency requirements. If a specific version is installed then it is there for a good reason. Removing one is likely to rid other packages along.

Finally use your distribution's package manager by all means to install packages and their dependencies, especially those that belong to the distribution's repository... unless impossible otherwise. I might be wrong but if you count on `pip` to update some of the main packages then the package manager will be confused and most probably mess up with the dependencies you satisfied by hand. (In fact it's the other way around: letting `pip` manage dependencies will likey mess up with `yum`.)

Comment: I think I do have 2 pythons. The directory /bin has both python2.7 and python3.3. And both pythons are still working. But, the yum --showduplicates python command reports only python 2.7.3-13.fc18. And when I tried to remove the python3.3 by yum remove python3.3, it reported that "No Packages marked for removal".

Comment: You can run `yum whatprovides /bin/python3.3` and see if it comes from a packages that was installed by yum. If `yum` finds no package, then that `python3.3` instance must have been installed manually as a dependency, by `pip` most probably. It is best to remove all of `python3.3` "manually" (i.e. with the tool that installed it), then install it with `yum` to keep a consistent dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks. I ran yum whatprovides /bin/python3.3 and yum whatprovides /bin/python2.7 respectively.The primay differences in results is that the repo of python3.3 is updates and the repo of python2.7 is installed. I guess this means that both are installed by yum?

Comment: I guess so. You know when a file does not belong to any package because `yum` tells you so. If you got results and no error message then `pyton3.3` must have been pulled down by `yum`.

Answer (score 3):

On all recent Fedora releases, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` — which means if you look in /bin, you actually get redirected to the /usr/bin. However, *both* appear in `$PATH` (hmmm; that probably should be cleaned up), and that's what you're seeing with `which -a python` — two ways to get to an actually-identical binary.

So, there's no problem here.

(Note, though, that mixing pip and rpm (yum) installation *can* give confusing results and possibly install duplicate versions of things.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. 
The problem has been solved.
I do have python3.3 and python2.7 on my computer.
I remove python3.3 by yum remove python3 .

The numpy problem is solved by addding

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/
```

to the `./bashrc`.

Comment: Why remove python3.3? It's a newer version of the language -- and it typically *doesn't* provide an executable named "python" (it's named "python3"). It shouldn't conflict with your Python 2 installation, and removing it means you can't run any scripts that depend on Python 3. (You can almost think of Python 2 and Python 3 as two different languages.)